# How to load Alpine Linux backed up configuration on boot?

Tags: linux, alpine-linux, vmware-workstation

I am running Alpine Linux by using the [alpine-standard-3.6.2-x86_64.iso](http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/releases/x86_64/alpine-standard-3.6.2-x86_64.iso) image on VMWare Workstation 12.5.5.

Following [this guide](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Install_Alpine_on_VMware) I've been able to configure, among others, root password, keyboard layout and network interfaces.

The gist of the process described in the guide is:

1. create and mount a floppy device
2. execute `setup-alpine`
3. execute `lbu commit floppy`

**The issue is that the saved configuration does not get loaded when I reboot the machine**

Here are some observations:

- when I mount the `/dev/fd0` floppy it contains a `localhost.apkovl.tar.gz` file
- running `lbu list-backup floppy` does not list anything after committing the configuration, the result is empty
- I have a disk attached to the VM, when running `setup-alpine` I designated the disk to be used as a `data` volume

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alpine Linux no longer support floppy. You will have to create a minimal hard disk image (32MB should do, depending a bit on how much configs you need), `mkfs.vfat /dev/sda` instead of `/dev/fd0`, mount it on `/media/usb` and make sure the `/dev/sda` is in your fstab. Then `lbu ci usb` or select `usb` when setup-alpine asks where to store the configs.

I have updated the wiki.

Comment: I put `/dev/sda` in the fstab file, saying it should mount on `/media/usb`, but at boot it gets mounted to `/media/sda`. I'm using Alpine 3.9 on ESXi. Followed https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Install_Alpine_on_VMware

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the guide you have followed has been updated:

https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Install_Alpine_on_VMware

since floppy is no longer supported.

Comment: I read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/603216/72988), for "persistant" storage on a mmc card do I need 4. echo "/dev/mmcblk0 /media/usb ext4 noatime,ro 0 0" >> /etc/fstab taken from [lbu docs](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_local_backup)?

Comment: There are high-level [commands](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installation) [and here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_setup_scripts) for my comment to this answer further up like `setup-alpine` and if not used setup-lbu to use local backup. So I do not need low level unix commands for it.